# Does Away3D 4.0 currently not work with AIR 3.0? Any fixes?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, away3d

I'm using AIR SDK Version 3.0.0.4080 and this build of Away3D ([https://github.com/away3d/away3d-core-fp11/](https://github.com/away3d/away3d-core-fp11/commit/3d71016e13346b80d61c8902629ee728f8460060)) building the project in FDT 5 on a Macbook Pro. The app descriptor file has renderMode set to direct.

I have been able to get Away3D 4.0 working with FP11 when it builds from the latest playerglobal.swc but when I attempt to build an AIR project then it appears the airglobal.swc is slightly different. `Filter3DTaskBase` throws errors due to differences in method parameters.

> Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 2.
>
> _program3D.upload(  new 
>   AGALMiniAssembler(Debug.active).assemble(Context3DProgramType.VERTEX,
>   getVertexCode(), Debug.active),

```
protected function updateProgram3D(stage : Stage3DProxy) : void
        {
            if (_program3D) _program3D.dispose();
            _program3D = stage.context3D.createProgram();
            _program3D.upload(  new AGALMiniAssembler(Debug.active).assemble(Context3DProgramType.VERTEX, getVertexCode(), Debug.active),
                                new AGALMiniAssembler(Debug.active).assemble(Context3DProgramType.FRAGMENT, getFragmentCode(), Debug.active));
            _program3DInvalid = false;
        }
```

and within `AGALMiniAssembler`:

```
public function assemble( mode:String, source:String, verbose:Boolean = false ):ByteArray
        {
                 ...
```

As far as I can see, the number of parameters match up. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.
I couldn't find anything about this in the Away3D forums or in the Issues on GitHub.

I am wondering if there is a deeper issue here with my graphics card etc as stage.displayState is behaving strangely as well, it behaves like the swf is running via the player not adl (needs MouseEvent to change to fullscreen). Although I have re-installed the latest flex sdk and AIR sdk in case something had gone wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was another version of AGALMiniAssembler that was in my source path due to its inclusion as part of the ND2D library. Once using the version Away3D expects, the app compiles correctly.